# Get-AzureVMDscExtensionStatus on Azure 9.1 is returning 404 blob errors

Tags: powershell, azure, dsc

I have provisioned my storageaccount with a simple Config to enable IIS, I have the subscription taken care of, the zip exists in blob storage, and appears to be setting just fine. Some output:

```
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Apply configuration 'IISInstall'" on target "VM".
[2015-05-18 21:58:13] With extensions added:
[2015-05-18 21:58:13] Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.Model.PersistentVM
OperationDescription : New-AzureService
OperationId          : 257df04c-cc1f-a4d5-a840-e127f9e799bd
OperationStatus      : Succeeded
```

I create the VM with no problems:

```
VERBOSE: 9:58:19 PM - Begin Operation: New-AzureVM - Create Deployment with VM fbconfigtest5
VERBOSE: 9:59:53 PM - Completed Operation: New-AzureVM - Create Deployment with VM fbconfigtest5
OperationDescription : New-AzureVM
OperationId          : 5063c04f-8902-abb2-838a-3d7f5f685bc2
OperationStatus      : Succeeded

VERBOSE: 9:59:54 PM - InstanceStatus is RoleStateUnknown
VERBOSE: 10:01:27 PM - InstanceStatus is Provisioning
VERBOSE: 10:05:36 PM - InstanceStatus is ReadyRole
[2015-05-18 22:05:36] Vm Created: 
[2015-05-18 22:05:36] Succeeded
```

And go into a polling loop to wait for the DSC to complete:

```
$status = Get-AzureVMDscExtensionStatus -ServiceName $ServiceName -Name $ServiceName

while($status.StatusCode -ne 1 -and $CurrTime -lt $TimeOut )
{
    $CurrTime = Get-Date
    $status = Get-AzureVMDscExtensionStatus -ServiceName $ServiceName -Name     $ServiceName -verbose
    write-log "Currents status is :"
    write-log $status.Status
    Write-log $status.StatusMessage
    write-log $status.DscConfigurationLog
    start-sleep -seconds 60
}
```

It takes about 5 minutes, but the three variation on status I report are as follows:

```
VERBOSE: 10:05:38 PM - Completed Operation: Get Deployment
WARNING: The specified resource extension reference cannot be found.
[2015-05-18 22:05:38] Currents status is :
```

...

```
VERBOSE: 10:07:43 PM - Completed Operation: Get Deployment
[2015-05-18 22:07:43] Currents status is :
[2015-05-18 22:07:43] Transitioning
[2015-05-18 22:07:44] Initializing DSC extension.
```

...

```
VERBOSE: 10:10:50 PM - Completed Operation: Get Deployment
[2015-05-18 22:10:50] Currents status is :
[2015-05-18 22:10:51] Transitioning
[2015-05-18 22:10:51] Rebooting VM to complete installation.
```

...

```
VERBOSE: 10:16:02 PM - Completed Operation: Get Deployment
[2015-05-18 22:16:02] Currents status is :
[2015-05-18 22:16:02] Error
[2015-05-18 22:16:02] An error occurred downloading the Azure Blob: Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."
The Set-AzureVMDscExtension cmdlet grants access to the blobs only for 1 hour; have you exceeded that interval?
```

This is very similar to the sample code in the following blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2015/02/27/introducing-get-azurevmdscextensionstatus-cmdlet-for-azure-powershell-dsc-extension.aspx

Did something break, is there a new naming convention used? Even if I set the Config again and update the vm like so:

```
$aVM = Get-AzureVM -ServiceName fbconfigtest5 -Name fbconfigtest5
$aVM = Set-AzureVMDscExtension -VM $aVM -ConfigurationArchive IISInstall.ps1.zip -ConfigurationName IISInstall -ContainerName windows-powershell-dsc
$aVM | Update-AzureVM
```

I still get the same error:

```
Get-AzureVMDscExtensionStatus -ServiceName $ServiceName -Name $ServiceName -verbose
VERBOSE: 10:51:06 PM - Completed Operation: Get Deployment

ServiceName         : fbconfigtest5
Name                : fbconfigtest5
Status              : Error
StatusCode          : -1
Timestamp           : 5/18/2015 10:13:55 PM
StatusMessage       : An error occurred downloading the Azure Blob: Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The remote server returned an 
                  error: (404) Not Found."
                  The Set-AzureVMDscExtension cmdlet grants access to the blobs only for 1 hour; have you exceeded that interval?
DscConfigurationLog : {}
```

Any Ideas, thoughts? I'll try being more explicit about my context, but according to my timestamps I'm almost out of the hour window for this VM. I will update with a super explicit Config storage, calling, and context settings when I get home.

Comment: All I could think is that the storage context you have isn't the right one and therefore your code cannot find the blob to pull down.

Comment: I just made another pass to see if the publish created a lease that timed out, but, alas... 
`[2015-05-18 23:22:53] fbconfigtest6'
VERBOSE: Configuration published to https://fbazureloggingstorage.blob.core.windows.net/windows-powershell-dsc/IIsInstall.ps1.zip
[2015-05-18 23:22:55] With extensions added:`

Comment: 20 minutes later the same error occurs.
`[2015-05-18 23:41:13] An error occurred downloading the Azure Blob: Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The remote server returned an erro
r: (404) Not Found."`
On the VM the log reads.

Comment: So I did get a 404 for that blob URL (I assume because the permissions on the container or blob are set to private.. which is cool for me). Try setting looser permissions on the blob or container (public?) If you do change the permissions you probably want to remove the comment with the URL.

Comment: Not worried about a Config file that turns on IIS.
URL from machine side log is this:
`VERBOSE: [2015-05-18T23:40:20] Downloading 
https://fbazureloggingstorage.blob.core.windows.net/windows-powershell-dsc/IISInstall.ps1.zip?sv=2014-02-14&sr=b&sig=zzeJbwgUtO
u%2FgD1GLbHWlF17YVUYsKcDby0CFy1ZJms%3D&se=2015-05-19T00%3A22%3A55Z&sp=rd to 
C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\1.10.1.0\bin\..\DSCWork\IISInstall.ps1.0\IISInstall.ps1.zip
VERBOSE: [2015-05-18T23:40:21] An error occurred processing the configuration package;`
blob is present and unlocked.

Comment: Have you tried w/o specifying the "-ContainerName windows-powershell-dsc".  I execute w/o this command and it works...the defaults will default to the storage account you are executing the powershell command in.  The other thing you could try is to use a fully qualified uri: https://<storageaccountname>.blob.ccore.windows.net/windows-powershell-dsc

Answer (score 0):

Randy,

Please make sure that you are using the same Storage Context as you used in `Publish-AzureVMDscConfiguration`, to publish the configuration archive, in the `Set-AzureVMDscExtension` cmdlet.

If that doesn't point you toward the problem, please add the full repro, including the details on how you are publishing the zip file to azure and try downloading the blob yourself using the new 'URL from machine side log' within an hour of running set.